# My app crashes with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm new to android and have a problem with my simple application.
I using a very simple counter using AsyncTask.

When I run the app and start the counter, it counts to 10, and then instead of printing "DONE!" the app just crushes, I have no idea why. Here's my code.
(The activity has 3 buttons to create, start and cancel the task).

```
public class AsyncTaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AsyncTask myAsyncTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_async_task);
    }

    public static void startActivity(Context context){

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AsyncTaskActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void createNewTask(View view) {

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
        myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(textView);
    }

    public void startTask(View view) {

        myAsyncTask.execute();
    }

    public void cancelTask(View view) {

        myAsyncTask.cancel(true);
    }

    private static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask{

        private TextView textView;

        public MyAsyncTask(TextView textView){

            this.textView = textView;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {


            for(int counter = 0; counter <= 10; counter ++){

                if(!isCancelled()) {
                    textView.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                    SystemClock.sleep(500);
                }
                else
                    break;
            }

            textView.setText("DONE!");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the crash log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot update UI from background thread mean the code inside `doInBackGround` runs on background thread

```
 @Override
 protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
     for(int counter = 0; counter <= 10; counter ++){

         if(!isCancelled()) {
             textView.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
             SystemClock.sleep(500);
         }
         else
             break;
        }

        textView.setText("DONE!");
        // ^^^^^ crash , cannot update UI from background thread
        return null;
    }
```

so instead use `onPostExecuted`

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        textView.setText("DONE!");
 }
```

Note:  if you cancel the task then you will find the same crash with `textView.setText(String.valueOf(counter));`.

---

Always use `generic` types and pass the resultant counter value and update UI accordingly.

```
private static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer>{

    private TextView textView;

    public MyAsyncTask(TextView textView){

        this.textView = textView;
    }


     protected Long doInBackground(Void... obj) {
        for(int counter = 0; counter <= 10; counter ++){

            if(!isCancelled()) {
                SystemClock.sleep(500);
                return counter;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
         return null;
     }


     protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        if(result != null)
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(result));
        else
            textView.setText(String.valueOf("Done"));
            // your current code will set done no matter the task is cancelled or not
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't edit View from AsyncTask doInBackground (only main thread). So move setText to onPostExecute

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

    textView.setText("DONE!");

}
```